# Cloning a RuntimeTypeModel to unfrozen state?

Tags: protobuf-net

is it possible to access an exist serialization model from defined model and then append a Contracted but unknown subtype to it, subsequently use it for serialization ?

or do i need to explicitly create a new model ? i.e. in this case for ModuleTwoFoo

---

### Update

```
var model = TypeModel.Create();
model[typeof(IFooChild)].AddSubType(2, typeof(ModuleTwoFooChild));
model.CompileInPlace();
```

**RuntimeModel.Default[] // model[] is the access ... Doh** !

my only complain if at all ... wish there was a way to access the original model then build on it rather than having regenerate the model again

As stated by marc "essentially what is required is cloned but unfrozen model"

---

```
public interface IFoo
{
    int FooNumber { get; set; }
    IList<IFooChild> Children { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract, ProtoInclude(1, typeof(ModuleOneFooChild))]
public interface IFooChild
{
    IFoo Foo { get; set; }
    string Detail { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class ModuleOneFoo : IFoo
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int FooNumber { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public IList<IFooChild> Children { get; set; }    
}

[ProtoContract]
public class ModuleOneFooChild : IFooChild
{
    public IFoo Foo { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Detail { get; set; }    
}

[ProtoContract]
public class ModuleTwoFoo : IFoo
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int FooNumber { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public IList<IFooChild> Children { get; set; }    
}

[ProtoContract]
public class ModuleTwoFooChild : IFooChild
{
    public IFoo Foo { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Detail { get; set; }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to make changes to a model after the serializer has been generated, which would nclude adding sub-types. That isn't currently supported - *at the current time* you would need to recreate the type-model. It is expected that you will know what you want to work with **before** you start working with it!

However, I can see value in one of two feature-requests:

1. To unfreeze a MetaType (blowing away any generated serializers/strategies)
2. To clone a MetaType or RuntimeTypeModel, but as not-frozen

Comment: Yes i got the part w.r.t serializer having to be immutable once generated. But option 2 was what i was hoping for, was initially unsure as how to formulate the question. "cloned but not frozen" would be perfect.